# numpy any() returning a peculiar result

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray `ary`

```
array([[ -8.34887715e-15],
       [ -8.57980353e-14],
       [ -7.28306304e-14]])
```

I am unable to understand the following:

```
ary.any() > 0.1
```

returns `True` even though each entry of `ary` is clearly below `0` (to my understanding this should evaluate to `False`).

If I however do

```
ary.any() > 1
```

this evaluates to `False`.

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ary.any()` returns `True` iff at least one element of `ary` is non-zero. You then check whether `True > .1`, which is true because `True` has the numerical value 1. What you meant was

```
(ary > .1).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

well `arr.any()` is used on boolean when you do ary.any() this evaluates to true and true > 1 is certainly false